# git asks to commit submodule modified content

Tags: git, git-submodules, youcompleteme

Recently I updated submodules in my vim configuration repository with this command:

```
git submodule update --recursive --remote
```

And when I called `git status` I got this:

```
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 5 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
  (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)

        modified:   .vim/pack/starter-pack/start/YouCompleteMe (modified content)

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Then I followed the chain of submodules that have "modified content" and found that the only modification was the untracked commits of submodules:

```
On branch master
Your branch is behind 'origin/master' by 1 commit, and can be fast-forwarded.
  (use "git pull" to update your local branch)
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   vendor/bottle (new commits)
        modified:   vendor/jedi (new commits)
        modified:   vendor/waitress (new commits)

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

master branches of these submodules (bottle, jedi, waitress) are behind master branches of their remote origins, so I suppose what `git submodule update` did is not just pull origins of each repo, but find appropriate version that parent repository requires.

Why even git marks this repos with `(new commits)` if it is exact commits that parent modules require? What is going on there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What has happened here is that your superproject is now inconsistent.  Specifically, your superproject has *gitlinks* that need to be committed.

You should add the new gitlinks (with `git add`, as usual) and commit (as usual).  You can then push your new commit (as usual).

#### Submodule implies superproject

A *submodule* is simply a Git repository that is being used directly by another Git repository.  The submodule itself, in this case, is just an ordinary Git repository: it has no knowledge of this other Git repository.  The other repository is the one we call the *superproject*, and it *does* know about the submodule.

#### Any Git repository needs a `.git` directory with some data

Typically, the way you create a Git repository is by cloning it from somewhere else:

```
git clone http://...
```

or whatever.  Or, you might run `git init` in a directory.  Either way, you end up with a `.git` directory that holds the Git repository itself.  In this `.git` you will typically have defined a *remote* named `origin`.  This is a short name (specifically, the name `origin`!) that records a URL, which is the URL you gave to `git clone` above.  This URL may even point to a repository of your own on, say, GitHub.

(If you started with someone else's repository, then decided to make your own on GitHub, you might even have *two* remotes.  Typically you would name your own repository `origin` and the other one `upstream`, but as far as Git itself is concerned, these are just arbitrary names.  The only reason we all agree on `origin` is that this is the name `git clone` creates for us, when we first run `git clone url`.)

Anyway, the data in the `.git` directory include the following:

- The URL for `origin`.
- The names of any branches, and the commit hash IDs those branches identify.
- Similarly, the names of tags, and their commits.
- The *current* commit: what, exactly, is checked out in the repository?  This may be a *branch name*, in which case the repository is *on a branch*, or it may be a raw commit hash ID, in which case the repository is in "detached HEAD" mode.

#### What if a superproject creates the submodule?

A superproject needs to know several things about each of its submodules.  First, the superproject has a file named `.gitmodules`.  Inside this `.gitmodules` file, you will find the *URL* for each submodule.  You will also find a *path* for each submodule.

The exact form and content of this file is described in [the gitmodules documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitmodules.html).  To quote it a bit, suppose it says:

```
[submodule "libfoo"]
        path = include/foo
        url = git://foo.com/git/lib.git
```

This means that when you clone the superproject, then run `git submodule init`, your Git will know that it should run `git clone git://foo.com/git/lib.git`—that's the *url* part—with the clone going into the `include/foo` directory: the *path* part.

There is one crucial piece missing from this puzzle.  After your Git clones another Git into `include/foo`, *what commit gets checked out in the submodule?*

In most normal repositories, this is not that big of a question.  What commit is checked out?  I don't know, I just run `git checkout master`, right?  That gets me the *latest* commit on branch `master`, which is what I want.

Superprojects and submodules don't work this way.  When I am using a submodule from my superproject, I build my superproject code around *one specific commit* in the submodule.  For instance, I might depend specifically on `v3.4.1` of someone else's library, so I would descend into the subproject and run `git checkout v3.4.1` to check out that particular *tag*.

Ideally, I might have my superproject record that tag (this would be nice, and gitlinks *ought* to allow this, but currently they don't).<sup>1</sup>  But a tag, in Git, is really just a human-readable name for one specific commit.  The tag `v3.4.1` might be the name for commit `feeddadac0ffee...` or some such.  That—the big ugly hash ID—is what actually goes into the gitlink.

The gitlink itself is stored in each and every commit, just like a regular file is stored in each and every commit.  If I make a new commit in the superproject with a new or modified `README` file, the new version of `README` goes into the Git repository, and the new commit refers to the new `README`.  Every commit after that continues to refer to the new `README`.

The same holds for a gitlink: if my `include/foo` refers to the hash ID for `v3.4.1` of the submodule, every commit from here on has a gitlink entry that says: "when you check out this commit, you should also go into the `include/foo` submodule and check out hash ID `feeddadac0ffee...`".

---

<sup>1</sup>If anyone wants to try to add this, I think there is a way to do it, that might even be somewhat backwards compatible: store a raw hash ID as usual, followed by a NUL byte, followed by the reference name.  An older Git that does not understand the new kind of gitlink could use the hash ID directly, and a newer Git could detect and use the name.  Gitlink entries are going to need a similar change anyway in the hash transition from SHA-1 to whatever Git uses in the future, so this might be a good time to add this.

---

#### What if the owner of the submodule makes a new release?

So, I have tested my superproject with `v3.4.1` and it all works.  Great!  But now whoever is in charge of this `include/foo` library has updated *their* code and released version `v3.4.2`.  This new version has some new feature, and I would like to use it.

I, as the owner of the superproject, should now go into my submodule and `git fetch` and then `git checkout v3.4.2`.  (This, rather than being `feeddadac0ffee`, is perhaps hash ID `deadcabbadcab005e...`.)  Then I should return to my superproject, make whatever changes are required to *use* the new submodule, test everything, and commit.

When I make the new commit to use `v3.4.2` of the submodule, I should not only commit *my* changes.  I also need to update my *gitlink*.  Since I have already done `git checkout deadcabbadcab005e`—or `git checkout v3.4.2`, which is the exact same thing, really—in the submodule, all I have to do is `git add include/foo` in my superproject.  This adds the updated gitlink to my index, so that when I run `git commit`, I record the *new* gitlink along with my other changes.

This makes a new commit, and I can now push my commit, if there is some other place I also keep my superproject (on GitHub or whatever).

Comment: Thank your for your answer and fulfilling explanation. But I was afraid to commit in other people repositories, because I thought that it may cause merge conflict in the future, when I update submodules again. Can merge conflict happen, if I commit this? And if it can, will it be resolved automatically? (I should have asked about it at first)

Comment: It's not at all clear to me whether you have made any commits in any of the sub-repositories. (`git submodule update --remote` does not, it merely changes *which commit you have selected*.) However, *all Git repositories are local by definition* and *all your repositories are your own*. This includes your submodule repositories: they are *yours*. You may have copied then from someone else but they are yours now. Only `git push`, if you do it, can affect someone else's repository (and then only if they allow it).